# É viável utilizar mais de um DbContext para no mesmo banco de dados?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Estou elaborando uma nova aplicação em `ASP.NET MVC` e pesquisando vi alguns exemplos de aplicações com mais de um contexto.

Digamos que minha aplicação tem vários módulos diferentes, mas todas as entidades tem ligação de alguma forma.

Nesse cenário, é viável utilizar mais de um contexto?

Posso acabar tendo problema com relacionamentos e acesso a dados?

Existe um motivo em especial pra utilizar vários contextos em um único banco de dados?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Nesse cenário, é viável utilizar mais de um contexto?

Sim, tanto é viável como recomendado para alguns casos, em que não é interessante a visibilidade de todas as entidades em um determinado contexto.

Por exemplo, no ASP.NET Identity, normalmente usa-se um contexto separado do restante da aplicação.

## Posso acabar tendo problema com relacionamentos e acesso a dados?

Pode. Por exemplo, se você fizer duas seleções em contextos diferentes e relacionar as entidade de algum modo (como no caso em que você queira criar registros associativos de cardinalidade n para n), poderá haver incoerências porque o contexto que salva pode entender o objeto do outro contexto como sendo um objeto novo, que ainda não existe, gerando até duplicações de dados.

## Existe um motivo em especial pra utilizar vários contextos em um único banco de dados?

Como já mencionado acima, em um cenário de autenticação e validação de logins é um cenário clássico para esta separação.

Outro motivo pode ser a velocidade. Contextos com muitos registros podem prejudicar a performance da aplicação. Neste caso, usa-se duas instâncias do mesmo contexto, sendo uma somente leitura e outra para persistência, com configurações de propriedades diferentes.

Answer (score 0):

Eu particulamente só utilizo mais de um DbContext para bases diferentes, resumindo crie dbcontext para bases diferentes, caso contrario nao vejo necessidade

Em alguns casos eu vejo pessoas criando mais de um dbcontext apenas para a area de login

Comment: Apenas como recomendação de resposta, procure centrar sua resposta mais em questões técnicas, e um pouco menos em experiências pessoais, que podem criar um ar baseado em opiniões, que é algo que o site procura evitar. Não que a experiência pessoal não possa e não deva ser mencionada, mas procure escrever uma resposta um pouco maior com uma base técnica um pouco mais densa. Por experiência isso garante mais upvotes e a resposta se torna mais interessante ;)

Comment: Legal @CiganoMorrisonMendez , obrigado pelo seu comentário sem questões técnicas, se quiser edita-lo sinta-se a vontade